# split different length column values to new columns/features

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this

**The f in the data set below coould be anything alphenumeric word i.e f=[A-z]+**

```
                 flags       perf
1   -f1 -arm -loop -f12=2.5  100
2                  -f1 -f44  45
3         -f12=1.89 -f1 -fA  450
4            -stkDump -fA56  590
```

each item in flags column **is a string**. I want to transform this data frame to something like this: some flags can have a **range of values e.g f12** in the above example and others are just on/off flags.

```
  f1 arm loop  f12  f44  fA stkDump fA56 perf
1  1  1  1     2.50   0  0   0       0  100
2  1  0  0     0.00   1  0   0       0  203
3  1  0  0     1.89   0  1   0       0   45
4  0  0  0     0.00   0  0   1       1  590
```

I'll be thankful if anyone can help, Please !

Comment: @A.Suliman it is a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `R` and `tidyverse`; the main trick is using `tidyr::separate_rows` to transfer `flags` into one column and many rows based on space, then use `stringr::str_extract` to extract the important information before transfer back into wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tdiyr)
df %>% 
   rownames_to_column(var="id_row")  %>% 
   separate_rows(flags,sep = '\\s') %>% 
   mutate(val=str_extract(flags,'\\d+\\.\\d+'), key=str_extract(flags,'f[0-9A-z]+')) %>% 
   mutate(val=ifelse(is.na(val),1,val)) %>% 
   dplyr::select(-flags) %>% spread(key, val, fill = 0)

    id_row perf f1  f12 f2 f44 f9 fA fA56 fAe
  1      1  100  1  2.5  1   0  1  0    0   0
  2      2   45  1    0  0   1  0  0    0   0
  3      3  450  1 1.89  0   0  0  1    0   0
  4      4  590  0    0  0   0  0  0    1   1
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text ="
                   flags perf
  1   '-f1 -f2 -f9 -f12=2.5'  100
                   2               '-f1 -f44'   45
                   3      '-f12=1.89 -f1 -fA'  450
                   4            '-fAe -fA56'  590
                   ",header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Please see the updated one above.

Comment: @Obiii you should provide all possibilities in your dataset before someone posted an answer, and shouldn't remove the tick mark if the answer answers the original question "OP", thus I've downvoted your question and voted to be closed. Change `f` to `[A-z]+` in key and you'll be fine.

Comment: @A Sorry, I had to untick it. I made changes to the question and tried your solution. It worked and I ticked the solution again. Thank you for your help :)